# Get PlatformException(exception, Unknown signInOption, null) with Google Signin Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use the signInWithGoogle method from Auth package.

https://pub.dev/packages/auth

I have the following exception and stack trace.

```
I/flutter (20513): Caught: PlatformException(exception, Unknown signInOption, null)
I/flutter (20513): Stack: #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
I/flutter (20513): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:316:33)
I/flutter (20513): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (20513): #2      MethodChannelGoogleSignIn.init (package:google_sign_in_platform_interface/src/method_channel_google_sign_in.dart:26:20)
I/flutter (20513): #3      GoogleSignIn._ensureInitialized (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:228:62)
I/flutter (20513): #4      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:210:11)
I/flutter (20513): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (20513): #5      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:266:18)
I/flutter (20513): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (20513): #6      GoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:336:9)
I/flutter (20513): #7      Auth.signInWithGoogle (package:auth/auth.dart:686:43)
I/flutter (20513): #8      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.start (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:43:6)
I/flutter (20513): #9      Auth.signInWithGoogle (package:auth/auth.dart:674:32)
I/flutter (20513): #10     _LoginPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:betting_ai/l
```

Here is the gist that I use:

https://gist.github.com/deadsoul44/f95c72c3d7a3529d4ac2efce751a3866

Any idea how to solve this issue?